# Typeerror in Django-Channels

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels

I am trying to send data from client-side in my django app but I keep getting this error and the socket disconnects. I am lost to why this is so, This is the error:

```
Exception inside application: receive() got an unexpected keyword argument 'text_data'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/MichaelAjanaku/Desktop/Kitchen-Order/order/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/staticfiles.py", line 44, in __call__
    return await self.application(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/MichaelAjanaku/Desktop/Kitchen-Order/order/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/routing.py", line 71, in __call__
    return await application(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/MichaelAjanaku/Desktop/Kitchen-Order/order/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/sessions.py", line 47, in __call__
    return await self.inner(dict(scope, cookies=cookies), receive, send)
  File "/Users/MichaelAjanaku/Desktop/Kitchen-Order/order/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/sessions.py", line 254, in __call__
    return await self.inner(wrapper.scope, receive, wrapper.send)
  File "/Users/MichaelAjanaku/Desktop/Kitchen-Order/order/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/auth.py", line 181, in __call__
    return await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/MichaelAjanaku/Desktop/Kitchen-Order/order/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/middleware.py", line 26, in __call__
    return await self.inner(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/MichaelAjanaku/Desktop/Kitchen-Order/order/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/routing.py", line 160, in __call__
    send,
  File "/Users/MichaelAjanaku/Desktop/Kitchen-Order/order/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/consumer.py", line 94, in app
    return await consumer(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/MichaelAjanaku/Desktop/Kitchen-Order/order/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/consumer.py", line 59, in __call__
    [receive, self.channel_receive], self.dispatch
  File "/Users/MichaelAjanaku/Desktop/Kitchen-Order/order/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/utils.py", line 51, in await_many_dispatch
    await dispatch(result)
  File "/Users/MichaelAjanaku/Desktop/Kitchen-Order/order/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/consumer.py", line 73, in dispatch
    await handler(message)
  File "/Users/MichaelAjanaku/Desktop/Kitchen-Order/order/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/generic/websocket.py", line 196, in websocket_receive
    await self.receive(text_data=message["text"])
TypeError: receive() got an unexpected keyword argument 'text_data'
WebSocket DISCONNECT /ws/orders/ [127.0.0.1:49984]
```

This is the consumers.py:

```
import json
from .models import Order
from channels.db import database_sync_to_async
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer

class WSConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    
    @database_sync_to_async
    def _get_order_info(self, number):
        order = Order.objects.get(order_number = number)
        return order

  
    async def connect(self):
        self.groupname = 'kitchen'
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
                    self.groupname,
                    self.channel_name,
                )      
        await self.accept()

   
    async def disconnect(self, code):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.groupname,
            self.channel_name,
        )
        await super().disconnect(code)



    async def take_order(self, event):
        number = event['number']
        details = event['details']
        info = await self._get_order_info(number)
        time_taken = info.order_date_time
        taken_by = info.taken_by
        fulfilled = info.is_fulfilled
        fulfilled_by = info.fulfilled_by

        await self.send(order_data=json.dumps({   
    
                'number' : number,
                'details' : details,
                'time_taken' : time_taken,
                'taken_by' : taken_by,
                'fulfilled' : fulfilled,
                'fulfilled_by' : fulfilled_by,        }))

    async def receive(self, order_data):
        order_data_json = json.loads(order_data)
        number = order_data_json['number']
        details = order_data_json['details']
        time_taken = order_data_json['time_taken']
        taken_by = order_data_json['taken_by']
        fulfilled = order_data_json['fulfilled']
        fulfilled_by = order_data_json['fulfilled_by']

        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.groupname,
            {   
                'type': 'take_order',
                'number' : number,
                'details' : details,
                'time_taken' : time_taken,
                'taken_by' : taken_by,
                'fulfilled' : fulfilled,
                'fulfilled_by' : fulfilled_by,   
            }
        )
```

Here is the Javascript code in the template:

```
var ws_url = 'ws://' + window.location.host + '/ws/orders/';
    var orderSocket = new WebSocket(ws_url);
    document.querySelector('#submit').onclick = function(e) {
        const numberInputDom = document.querySelector('#id_order_number');
        const detailsInputDom = document.querySelector('#id_order_details');
        const number = numberInputDom.value;
        const details = detailsInputDom.value;
        orderSocket.send(JSON.stringify({
            'number': number,
            'details' : details,
        }));
        console.log('data sent')
       
    };
```

Any reason why I am getting that particular error? I have been battling it all day.

Comment: Change `async def receive(self, order_data):` to `async def receive(self, text_data):`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because the function is called with the keyword argument `text_data` which you have named `order_data`.

You need to rename your parameter in order for it to work.

```
async def receive(self, text_data):
    order_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
    # Rest of the code ...
```